# NS record for subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a rather complex stack being managed with over 8 subdomains, however the domain is managed by an IT department. As a solution to gain control of record management I wanted to set the subdomain up to a separate NS manager. I'm wondering if the following is valid and will work as I expect:

mysub.thedomain.com will have an NS record pointing to CloudFlare:

```
harvey1.cloudflare.com
harvey2.cloudflare.com
harvey3.cloudflare.com
```

thedomain.com has many other subdomains but none collide with `mysub`. Once the NS record is configured I should be able to create any domain as I need ie. `anothersub.mysub.thedomain.com` as an A record to a server.

My understanding is that when anothersub.mysub.thedomain.com is looked up it'll do it in reverse order and follow the NS. Is this true? If not is there a way to accomplish my need?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is sound, your question is confusing.

If you want to delegate a subdomain, just add BS records in the name server for that domain and then set up the subdomain as a new zone and lookups will be forwarded in - eg for the "main domain" add

```
  mysub.example.com NS harvey1.cloudlare.com.
  mysub.example.com NS harvey2.cloudflare.com.
  mysub.example.com NS harvey3.cloudflare.com.
```

(Same as you would in a cname, be careful if you need a . at the end of each fqdn - which will depend on the name server/interface.)

In your new zone (mysub.example.com), specify the same name servers as above .

Note that this only handles forward DBS. Reverse DNS is a lot more complex and uses tricks and ptr records in the "ARPA" domain.